# RabbitMQ How can a publisher know if a message was recieved by the broker

Tags: rabbitmq, broker

I'm working with RabbitMQ in java. I'd like to publish multiple messages, knowing if the broker recieved it or not. Note that i don't want to know if the message was acknowledged or not. The examples I found seem to rely in the client sending a basicAck or Nack.

```
ch.setConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {
    public void handleAck(long seqNo, boolean multiple) {
        if (multiple) {
            unconfirmedSet.headSet(seqNo+1).clear();
        } else {
            unconfirmedSet.remove(seqNo);
        }
    }
    public void handleNack(long seqNo, boolean multiple) {
        // handle the lost messages somehow
    }
});
```

I only want to know if the message was recieved in the broker as a publisher, after a basicPublish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms).

The ACK's usage you are citing is for consumers, since RabbitMQ require a message to be ACKed, before removing it from its queues.

Note that receiving a confirm for a published message, does not imply that the message has been stored in a queue: that message can be "unroutable", and in this case the confirms are sent to the publisher immediately, but the message discarded. See: [When will messages be confirmed](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#when-publishes-are-confirmed)

If you want to track also unroutable messages, you have to use [Alternate Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html).